# Loop for string entries

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, do-while, c-strings

I am new to programming.
I am trying to get result (in C) from below code but failed.
I am trying to take input from user but enter into a loop if the entry is incorrect and proceed further if entry is correct.

```c
scanf("%s",employee.gender);
do
{
    printf("Invalid entry");
    printf("\nEnter Employee's Gender (Male/Female): ");
    scanf("%s",employee.gender);
}
while (employee.gender != "Male");
```

Comment: Also, your loop will *always* get entered because it is a do...while loop.  Maybe you want to use a regular `while` loop.

Comment: You can't compare strings in C like that. Look up the standard library function strcmp(). Also, do-while loops execute at least once. Perhaps a while loop instead that has the test at the top of the loop?

Comment: `employee.gender != "Male"` is incorrect. Use `memcmp(employee.gender, "Male", 5)` instead.

Comment: @DavidGrayson: I'm not sure if that question is a good duplicate target, because that question has a serious unrelated issue: It makes use of `gets` in several places. However, apart from that issue, it is a perfect duplicate target.

Answer (score 1):

To compare "strings" in C you need to use `strcmp()`, a function defined in `string.h` header, which takes 2 arguments `string1` and `string2` and compares them, returning:

- **0** if they're equal;
- **-1** if `string1` precedes alphabetically `string2`;
- **1** otherwise.

I've put it in quotes because C language doesn't have a proper string abstraction. Instead, strings are represented as an array of char values: `char str[MAX_STR_LENGTH];`. In order to use `strcmp()` function you need to include the header where it's declared, so you need to insert `#include <string.h>` at the top of your file.

The reason why you cannot use the `==` operator, is because when you try to compare 2 arrays that way you're actually comparing the two arrays' *memory addresses*, which are obviously different for different arrays.
Instead, `strcmp()` function loops over both of the arrays and checks for differences between their elements, one character by one.

---

#### Further considerations

Your code presents some conceptual mistakes:

- you're reading the input 2 times before checking the while condition;
- for each loop cycle you're printing the error message before checking the condition.

A better solution would be the following:

```c
do
{
    printf("Enter Employee's Gender (Male/Female)");
    scanf("%s", employee.gender);
    if (strcmp(employee.gender, "Male") != 0 && strcmp(employee.gender, "Female") != 0)
    {
        printf("Invalid entry\n");
    }
} while (strcmp(employee.gender, "Male") != 0 && strcmp(employee.gender, "Female") != 0);
```

Comment: @AndreasWenzel I'm trying to find a way to explain it in a better way :)

Comment: This is the exact result, I was looking for. Thank you for correcting me with your guidance.